# What is the best way to set up a potentiometer to run an 18 V battery to power a motor with these parameters?

Tags: batteries, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

[image]

These are the values on the tech sheet for the small motor I picked up. I just want to be able to have an 18 V battery power the motor, but I would like to regulate it, and would be running it around 9-10 volts on average, but would like to vary it from 6-12 volts. What is going to be my best option, without having to purchase and test several potentiometers? Or is that basically what I have to do? I don't want to resist the current too much and waste the power, I also don't want the potentiometer to heat up or fail...

Comment: A potentiometer is absolutely NOT the way to vary the speed (voltage) to the motor. You need an adjustable DC-DC convertor to be most efficient, though you could use a linear regulator.

Comment: AJ, keep in mind that if you might want to operate this motor from only 6 V, while drawing current from an 18 V power supply, you will have to dissipate the other 12 V in your regulator (if it is a simple linear regulator.) This means 1/3rd of the power to your motor and 2/3rds of the power wasted in the regulator. (It gets better when running the motor with a higher voltage. But this is an argument for applying a more complicated solution, if you want to keep your regulator running cooler and lighten the load on the 18 V supply.)

Comment: So if I only need ten volts would you recommend simply running with a 12 v battery? Maybe two wired together? And what exactly is a dc-dc convertor? And how small do they come? Does it come with a dial in the same format as a potentiometer? I'm making it a battery power with a power control knob...

Answer (score 0):

This is really crusty method to control motor speed using only potentiometer cause you need to pass 2.5A through so you gonna need high power Potentiometer. More efficient way is to control BJT by using Potentiometer and that BJT will control the speed of dc motor.

Check the attached Schematic[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the maximum continuous input of 3 watts, the motor will draw 3W/12.6V = 0.24 amps. If you want to drop 18 volts down to 6 volts while the motor is producing full torque, you will need (18 - 6)/0.24 = 50 ohms in series with the motor. The power dissipated will be 0.24^2 x 50 = 2.9 watts. If you can find a 50 ohm, 5 watt potentiometer and connect it as a rheostat, that will give you some degree on control. The speed will be dependent on load.